# Problem to calculate this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Hi I have the following problem:

> Let $B:=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x²+y²+z²=1, z\geq 0$ be the surface of the upper half of a ball with radius $1$ centered in $(0,0,0)$ with the vector field $a(x,y,z)=(-y,x,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Calculate $\int_B\operatorname{curl}(a)d\vec{F}$.

So $\operatorname{curl}(a)=((0-0),(0-0),(1-(-1))=(0,0,2)$
But I don't know what $d\vec{F}$ is.
How do I proceed here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem): your [flux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_vector_fields) through the surface $B$ (see those wikipage for more information about $d\vec{F}$)  is equal to the line integral of ${\bf a}$ along $\gamma=\partial B$ which is the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ in $z=0$:
$$\iint_B\operatorname{curl}({\bf a})d{\bf S}=\int_{\gamma}{\bf a}\cdot d{\bf r}=\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}(-\sin t,\cos t,0)\cdot (-\sin t,\cos t,0) dt=2\pi$$
where we used the parametrization of $\gamma$ given by  ${\bf r}(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, 0)$ with $t\in [0,2\pi)$.

P.S. Note the result is $2$ times the area of the unit disc, this is precisely the flux of $\operatorname{curl}({\bf a})=(0,0,2)$ through the unit disc $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ in $z=0$ with normal vector $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: How do you come from $$\int_{\gamma}{\bf a}\cdot d{\bf r}$$ to $$\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}(-\sin t,\cos t,0)\cdot (-\sin t,\cos t,0) dt$$?

Comment: Th first vector is $a$ along the unit circle and the second one is the derivative of $r$. See my edited answer.

Comment: I didn't read your answer completely but I believe it's correct, HOWEVER, the OP asks for the meaning of $d\vec{F}$ and you totally ignore that in your answer..... yeah we can assume it's the normal but still, strictly speaking, we cannot assume it.

Comment: @Anonymous You are right, I forgot to mention it. I edited my answer with two links to wiki-pages.